# Get All Variations from number of options

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
options = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I want to extract all variations from those options with all possible directions as string separated by comma and space , it should looks like:

```
Variations = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A, B', 'A, C', 'A, B, C','A, C, B', 'B, A', 'B, C', 'B, A, C', 'B, C, A', 'C, A', 'C, B', 'C, B, A', 'C, A, B']
```

In my experiments I used the following method to get almost what I want, but not exact

```
options = ['A', 'B', 'C']

const powerSet = arr => {
  return arr.reduce(
    (total, value) =>
      total.concat(
        total.map(totalItem => [value].concat(totalItem).join(', '))
      ),
    [[]]
  )
}

const rightLeftArray = powerSet(options)
const leftRightArray = powerSet(options.reverse())

const mergedArrays = rightLeftArray.concat(leftRightArray)

const filteredArray = mergedArrays.filter(el => el.length !== 0)
const uniqArray = [...new Set(filteredArray)]

console.log('uniqArray', uniqArray)

// I Got this result:
uniqArray = ["A", "B", "B, A", "C", "C, A", "C, B", "C, B, A", "B, C", "A, C", "A, B", "A, B, C"]
```

I appreciate if you could get more accurate results with minimum code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a recursive function that produces all combinations of input elements and returns an array of results like below.

The *memo* array is used to remember if an element has already been added in a previous function call so we don't add it again.

We use a *slate* to accumulate the current state, then push the *joined* state to the results array on each iteration.

***Note:***

1. If there is only one item in an array the [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method will return the item without the separator.
2. I added a timer to measure the execution time with [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now). The running time for an input array of 5 elements is around ~0.3 ms.

**Test below:**

```js
const getCombinations = (options) => {
  const results = [];

  const helper = (slate, level, end, memo) => {
    for (let i=0; i <= end; i++) {
      if (memo[i] !== 1) {             // you can also use !memo[i]
        memo[i] = 1;
        slate.push(options[i]);
        results.push(slate.join(", "));
        if (level != end) {
          helper(slate, level + 1, end, memo);
        }
        slate.pop();
        memo[i] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  helper([], 0, options.length - 1, []);
  return results;
}


const options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

let t0 = performance.now();
let result = getCombinations(options);
let t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Execution time: " + (t1 - t0));
console.log(result);
```

### Explanation:

To keep it simple, lets take a smaller example with an input of:

```
const options = ['A', 'B']
```

**Diagram**

[image: Recursive Variations Diagram]

The green arrows above depict successfully satisfying the if condition

```
if (memo[i] !== 1)
```

and adding the character `options[i]` to the slate. This means that the character at *ith* position in *options* was not added to the slate (at any position) in a previous function call. We now have to mark `memo[i] = 1` before making the next function call so that we skip that character in all subsequent function calls.

The yellow arrows depict a character getting popped out of the slate in order for the next character to be put in it's place (e.g. if we never popped out the last item in the slate combinations starting with *B* would have never existed). We then also have to mark `memo[i] = 0` so that the current (*ith*) character can be used in subsequent function calls.

Each time we make a subsequent function call we increase the level

```
helper(slate, level + 1, end, memo);
```

so that we know when to stop making further calls (when level reaches `options.length-1`, since level starts at `0` and we want our combinations to be of max size `options.length`):

```
if (level != end)
```

After the subsequent function call returns the for loop then increments `i` and the next character in *options* will be added to the slate, creating a brand new combination.

The reason this works is because each function call has a for loop that starts from `i=0`. The *memo* array is then checked on each iteration to figure out which character can be used. We see from the diagram that because of this the combinations `['A','A']` and `['B','B']` were skipped.

Comment: Clever solution. Can you explain the purpose of slate.pop() ; and memo[i] = 0; in the inner loop?.. I made some tests and for some degree, it's faster.. The if statement eliminates many unneeded operations.

Comment: @M.Dev I edited to include an explanation. It's not very easy to explain so if you have any questions please feel free to ask so I can get ideas on how to make the explanation better for future readers.

Comment: Always I get confused with recursive functions. So I prefer to write down an algorithm ( step by step process ) before going forward. In all cases your answer is the best so far.

Comment: @M.Dev recursion can be tricky to understand. Drawing a diagram like above always helps. There a few other ways to solve this problem like using swapping but I find them harder to understand and they don’t get a better running time nor do they use less code. As far as the running time this is as fast as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

Would that work?

```js
const options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

const variations = new Set(options)

let t0 = performance.now()

// 1nth variations are already initialized in `variations` Set
for (i = 2; i <= options.length; i++) {
  // We run this n-1 times so that each time, new added variations
  // are based on previous variations, run once again against all options
  options.forEach(o => 
    variations.forEach(v => {
     // Do not add same value two times in one variation, such as 'A, A'
     if (v.indexOf(o) !== -1) return
     // `variations` is a Set so it will not store duplicates
     variations.add(`${v}, ${o}`) 
    })
  )
}


let t1 = performance.now()

console.log("Execution time: " + (t1 - t0))
console.log("Number of variations: ", variations.size)
```

Edit: edited to output performance, which is between 2 and 3 worse than Ivan solution below

Comment: Thank you. You got the exact suggested results, but if we try to raise the number of options, say ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], we will  get performance issues, even my browser suspended for a while.